# Translate test inside div in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, html

I have this piece of code inside

> **app\design\frontend\Company_name\porto_base_child\Magento_Checkout\web\template\shipping.html**

```
<div id="poboxmessage" style="display: none; color: red;">address</div>
```

I am trying to display this div inside this file at the bottom which is working fine on English page but not getting translated to french.

> **app\design\frontend\Company_name\porto_base_child\Magento_Checkout\web\js\view\shipping-address\list-dropdown.js**

```
$.mage.__(document.getElementById('poboxmessage').style.display='block');
```

I have put the translation of english to french inside

> **app\design\frontend\Company_name\porto_base_child\i18n\fr_CA.csv**

"address","adresse"

Also the translation in

> **app\code\Company_name\Catalog\view\frontend\web\js\fr_ca.js**

```
$.mage.__("address");
```

I am able to display text only in English on both english and french pages the issue is just my text is not getting translated some how. I am still trying to figure out if I have missed any steps. Any advice or suggestion would help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('poboxmessage').style.display='block';
         document.getElementById('poboxmessage').innerHTML=$.mage.__(document.getElementById('poboxmessage').innerHTML);
```

I was misinterpreting that my div returns a string in block inside mage functionality rather it needs to be converted to block first and then into plain text. $.mage returns just a string while (__) is function which takes of translation putting whole chunk of `document.getElementById('poboxmessage').style.display` inside $.mage function would not understand anything and returns just a string block